# Systemd unit file for Gunicorn & WSGI with virtualenv

Tags: flask, gunicorn, systemd

I'm trying to run a flask app with Nginx and Gunicorn on Fedora 37. Part of this involves creating a Systemd unit file, thus:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pretox
Group=pretox
WorkingDirectory=/home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager
ExecStart=/home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/gunicorn_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's the script that's called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. /home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/virtualenv/bin/activate
/home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --timeout 120 --name ptox-metdata-manager --user pretox --group pretox --log-level debug --error-logfile /home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/error.log  --bind unix:/home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/ptox-metadata-manager.socket wsgi:app
```

Systemd is not willing to start Gunicorn:

```
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-01-25 09:51:22 GMT; 3s ago
   Duration: 4ms
    Process: 52572 ExecStart=/home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/gunicorn_start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 52572 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

Jan 25 09:51:22 catoblepas systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.
Jan 25 09:51:22 catoblepas systemd[52572]: gunicorn.service: Failed to locate executable /home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/gunicorn_start: Permission denied
Jan 25 09:51:22 catoblepas systemd[52572]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/pretox/ptox-metadata-manager/gunicorn_start: Permission denied
Jan 25 09:51:22 catoblepas systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 25 09:51:22 catoblepas systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm not sure why permission should be denied here. Could it be SELinux interfering?

```
(virtualenv) [pretox@development ptox-metadata-manager]$ ls -Z gunicorn_start 
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 gunicorn_start
```

If I run the command line from the gunicorn_start script then it starts up and Nginx is able to proxy to it.

Comment: From the systemd tag: Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed eventually discover that; answer below.

Comment: The point is, your question is off topic, as evidenced by the tag and that you found an answer on a different Exchange site. You need to delete this one.

Comment: I am agreeing with your point, but did not infer from it that deletion was a necessity.

Comment: Being off topic requires removal. It is up for removal so it will happen eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be moving the bash script to /usr/local/bin, as described here; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664811/systemd-service-failing-with-exit-code-status-203-exec